# I got the problem on the guildMemberAdd event on Discord.js v13.8.0

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I got the problem on the guildMemberAdd event. When the event run, I got the error.

[This is the console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMiG1.png)

Here's my code (index.js):

```
const { Client, Intents, Collection } = require('discord.js');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const fs = require('fs');

const client = new Client({ intents: 32767 });
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello Express app!');
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('server started');
});
//--------------------Discord Bot Code below -----------

client.commands = new Collection();
client.cooldowns = new Collection();

['eventsHandler', 'commandsHandler'].forEach(handler => {
  require(`./Handlers/${handler}`)(client);
})


client.login(process.env['TOKEN']); //Login With Discord Token
```

And guildMemberAdd.js

```
module.exports = {  
  name: "guildMemberAdd",
  execute(member) {
    try {
      console.log(member.guild.name); //<--- The problem's here
    } catch (ex) {
      console.error(ex);
    };
  };
};
```

Please help me. :((

Comment: Can you show your event handler file as one reason behind the error might be incorrect arguments passed in

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

[Here's my event handler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igPkb.png)

```
const { readdirSync } = require('fs')

module.exports = (client) => {
  const eventFolders = readdirSync(`./Events`)
  for (const folder of eventFolders) {
    const eventFiles = readdirSync(`./Events/${folder}`).filter(files => files.endsWith(".js"))
    for (const file of eventFiles) {
      const event = require(`../Events/${folder}/${file}`)
      if (event.once) {        
        client.once(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args, client))
      } else {
        client.on(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args, client))
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is not how you fire the `guildMemberAdd` event.

it's a client parameter, so you need to do this

```js
client.on('guildMemberAdd', async (member) => {
     // Your code here 
});
```

Read the [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildMemberAdd)

Comment: Nahhh It's not working. It still say the same.